# Show other image on mouse hover with fade effect issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I´m trying to change my images on mouse hover to other image with fade effect. I think I´m doing everything correct but its not working and my image that I want to appear first is hidden but I dont understand why this is happening, because I think the code is right!
Do you see any issue in the code?

**My Html:**

```
<section id="body-container">
    <div id="body">
        <div id="body-content">

            <article id="loop-news">   
                <img id="hidden">   
                <img id="show" src="images/image1.jpg"  />
                <h2>Title 1</h2>
                <p>Post 1</p>
            </article>

            <article id="loop-news">
                <img id="hidden">   
                <img id="show" src="images/image1.jpg"  />
                <h2>Title 2</h2>
                <p>Post 2</p>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**My jQuery:**

```
$('#show').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true).fadeTo("slow", 0);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop(true).fadeTo("slow", 1);
});
```

My css:

```
#hidden {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 160px;
    background: red;
    z-index: -1
}
```

Comment: Your HTML doesn't seem to match your CSS/jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, When I was passing the code from here I forget that essencial part. Thanks for your answer! I update it now how I have here!

Comment: you are using `img` tag twice with same id `show`, infact there is other same id, `hidden` and `loop-news`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have repeating IDs, which **you cannot have**. You should change them to classes and use `.className` instead

You also need to have `position:relative;` on the container (`loop-news`) to make the `position:absolute` for the hidden images to work correctly

```
.loop-news {
    position:relative;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4srfR/)

Also, instead of using an id `#body`, just use the `<body>` element or preferably rename to something else. It doesn't make sense to have a `<section>` tag around the body

Comment: Its not possible put the second image that appears on the hover with opacity? to be transparent? I´m trying with "opacity:0.4;" but its not working. Like this: <img class='hidden' src="http://placehold.it/350x150" style="opacity:0.4;" />

Comment: @John23 Sure you can make it less opaque. http://jsfiddle.net/4srfR/1/ I applied it to the `.hidden` class

Comment: Thanks but I already try that but its not that that I want..I want to the image be transparent so I can see the other image behind...do you understand?

Comment: @John23 Then apply it to show and change the jQuery to the value you set.... http://jsfiddle.net/4srfR/2/

Answer (score 1):

There is same ids are using fo different elements like

`loop-news` for `article` element

`hidden` for `img` element

`show` for `img` elemnt

The id is unique. it should be used only once for a element in html.